# Big O notation O(p^2 log p)

Tags: big-o

Please help me to describe and solve that why

Θ(p^2 log p^2) = Θ(p^2 log p)

I really got stun on it.

Comment: @Klaus Byskov Hofmann Haha. Best laugh of today :)

Answer (score 7):

log (p^2) = 2 log p (as in general, [log (n^m) = m log n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities))

Since 2 is just a constant, we have that Θ(log p^2) = Θ(log p).

Therefore, we get Θ(p^2 log p^2) = Θ(p^2 log p).

Answer (score 1):

If `x = log p^2` that means that `e^x = p^2`. That means that `sqrt(e^x) = p`, and so `e^(x*1/2) = p`. So `(log p^2)/2 = log p`. This means that `p^2 log p^2 = 2 p^2 log p`; since this is big-theta constant multipliers can be discarded, so they turn out equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to start with definition! [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation):

> Big-O notation describes the limiting
>   behavior of a function when the
>   argument tends towards a particular
>   value or infinity

Limiting behavior is same for functions `f` and `g`, if `g = C*f`. Asymptotically they behave the same. Now to `log`. Remeber the formula:

log<sub>b</sub>x<sup>y</sup> = y log<sub>b</sub>x

It means that they are different only by constant, which doesn't change limitting behavior.

But it is importand to remember that their speed and amount of operations are still different (by constant).

Answer (score 0):

I presume because log(x^n) = nlog(x).  And n is a constant, therefore not relevant in Big O.  To put it another way, O(n) = O(2n) because they're both twice as bad when n doubles.